# How to test whether my IQueryable will actually compile down to SQL

Tags: c#, testing, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I have a project running on EF (6.0) and attempting to use OData to allow easy tabulation functionality.

In order to achieve this, we have lots of vertical slices that are handling `IQueryable<T>` right from the `DbContext` up to the Controller.
We are mapping our domain models to VMs in those slices, which works because LinqToEntities is insanely powerful, and converts those C# object mapping statements into SQL. Our mapping method takes an `IQueryable<DomainModel>`, calls `.Select()` and returns an `IQueryable<ViewModel>`

But some of our mapping code is sufficiently complex that we're pushing the bounds of what LinqToEntities can handle, so sometimes we write code that compiles, but at runtime LinqToEntities tells us that it's too hard and isn't supported:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

That's fine and we're happy to work within those constraints. But I'd quite like to have a quick Unit Test that warns me about such errors.

**How can I UnitTest whether my mapping code is compatible with LinqToEntities?**

---

I was hoping that I could just run the mapping method in a unit test, with a stubbed out underlying `IQueryable`, but that doesn't seem to be working.

See here for a direct question about *that* error: [Error when trying to test an isolated IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376855/error-when-trying-to-test-an-isolated-iqueryable)

But I'm not certain that that would actually work, even if I could make the code execute?

What's the best way to achieve this goal?

Comment: I know that's not what you have in mind for *unit* tests, but I'm pretty sure the only feasible strategy for eliminating runtime query translation errors is to automatically create a test database and run the queries against it in your tests.

Comment: @JonasHøgh Yeah, I suspect that may be the only solution. Just hoping someone else has a brainwace :)